# Apache Cordova: how to block network access in config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, networking, block

Even looking at Cordova 3.5.0 documentation, I cannot find a way to block network access from my android application. I have erased line

```
<access origin="*" />
```

from my config.xml in the application root directory

but when I install my app on a device it says that it will access full network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission may be located in the `AndroidManifest.xml` at `platforms\android` directory

The value is as shown below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought all parameters were configurable in Cordova to avoid conflict.

Comment: This is still the case for corodova 5.0.0.